# "..., that is:" vs. "...,i.e.,"

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

I know *i.e.* and *that is* are equivalent, but I have seen a *...that is:* also. Does this construction differ in meaning?

See:

> It does not regard politics as a separate or primary goal, that is: as
>   a goal that can be  achieved without a wider ideological context."

vs.

> It does not regard politics as a separate or primary goal, i.e., as
>   a goal that can be  achieved without a wider ideological context."

Looks exactly the same to me, yes? Is this just the authors particular style that I'm reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any advantage in putting a colon after "that is" in the first example. A colon or semicolon generally indicates a more-significant break in the flow of a sentence than a comma does, but in that first example the biggest break in continuity occurs just before "that is," not just after—and since you've relied on a comma there, it doesn't make much sense to bring in the bigger weaponry in a lesser cause two words later.

In my view, you could certainly get away with all-comma internal punctuation, in your first example, just as you do (aside from the periods in "i.e.") in the second example:

> It does not regard politics as a separate or primary goal, that is, as a goal that can be achieved without a wider ideological context.

If you want to use stronger punctuation to indicate the major break in continuity in that example, you can do so with a colon (arguably) or with an em-dash (my preference):

> It does not regard politics as a separate or primary goal—that is, as a goal that can be achieved without a wider ideological context.

Indeed using the stronger em-dash (or colon) treatment makes it easier to omit the "that is" altogether, if you aren't especially attached to it:

> It does not regard politics as a separate or primary goal—as a goal that can be achieved without a wider ideological context.

Aside from the misplaced colon in your original example, example 1 (with "that is") and example 2 (with "i.e.") are functionally identical. Some style manuals advise authors to use complete words (such as "that is") instead of abbreviations (such as "i.e."), but different publications have different rules on this point.

Comment: Nice logical treatment of sensible use of punctuation, but I must upvote for 'bring in the bigger weaponry' for 'use a colon here'. Perhaps the interrobang will need a nuclear metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they look  the same to you is because *they are*:

But one is plain English, whereas the other is Latin.

"**i.e.**" is an abbreviation for "id est", literally "it is".

English has quite a few Latin abbreviations still in use. Other examples are

- **e.g.** (exemplia gratia / sometimes: exemplum gratum = "for (the sake of the) example", lit. "free example"),
- **etc.** (et cetera = "and the rest"),
- **et al.** (et alii = "and the others")

Comment: I thought i.e. stood for the French "il est" meaning "he is". Anyway, yours seems more plausible

Comment: There are many sources, e.g. Merriam Webster (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/i.e.), that agree on i.e. being Latin.

Comment: Haven't these abbreviations been in use long enough for them to be accepted as English now? Is 'blitz' still classed as German?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - that is a question which I happily leave for native speakers and linguists to decide: I am neither.